# Can TAI time be represented by ISO 8601 and if so how?

Tags: datetime, iso8601

ISO 8601 specifies a format for representing date and time. For example the time part might be 18:34:12Z, with the Z suffix indicating that this is UTC time.

TAI is another time standard which is currently (as of writing) offset from UTC by 37 seconds, essentially due to leap seconds in UTC, but not in TAI.

Can I represent a TAI time using ISO 8601?

Clearly the Z suffix alone is not appropriate, as TAI is not UTC. ISO 8601 does permit time offsets from UTC, but the examples I can find are regarding time zones and are only ever represented as hours and minutes, e.g 18:34:12Z+05:30 as used for local time in India.

Is it permitted to use something like 18:34:12Z+00:00:37 to represent a Time in TAI?

I cannot find any documentation to indicate whether seconds are allowed in the offset. Perhaps there is a better way to represent TAI time?

Apologies if this is on the incorrect stack exchange site - All ISO 8601 questions I could find were in Stack Overflow, but I'm not sure this is directly a programming question. I couldn't find a better site though and I'm asking the question because I'm writing code that needs to output dates and times.

Comment: I don't think a UTC offset in seconds is specified by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators), but I don't see why it should be *permitted*. However the question to me is *is it reasonable to use such offset*? - And I think *no* since I suspect this will cause many parsers to fail or just ignore the seconds. So maybe it would be better to convert [TAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Atomic_Time) to UTC and then format according to ISO 8601.

Comment: Just leave off the Z, for example, 18:34:12. This indicates local time, and the data recipient is put on notice to determine which variety of local time using information outside the ISO8601 representation.

Comment: @GerardAshton Local time is not the same as a worldwide time in TAI. There's no way to convert from one to the other.

Comment: IN ISO 8601, "local time" means that none of the standard time zone indications, such as Z, +1, -5, etc., apply. The person reading the time is put on notice to examine information outside of the ISO-8601 notation to find out what kind of time is being represented. This outside information could be a statement that the time is TAI.

Answer (score 1):

As an answer to my own question (some significant time later). I found the following in [RFC 3339:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339)

> Numeric offsets are calculated as "local time minus UTC".  So the
> equivalent time in UTC can be determined by subtracting the offset
> from the local time.  For example, 18:50:00-04:00 is the same time as
> 22:50:00Z.  (This example shows negative offsets handled by adding
> the absolute value of the offset.)

> NOTE: Following ISO 8601, numeric offsets represent only time
> zones that differ from UTC by an integral number of minutes.
> However, many historical time zones differ from UTC by a non-
> integral number of minutes.  To represent such historical time
> stamps exactly, applications must convert them to a representable
> time zone.

The implication is therefore that only whole minutes are allowed in the offset. So it seems that TAI cannot be represented as I suggested above. Instead, you apparently need to convert it to UTC or some other time zone. It seems TAI cannot be directly represented in ISO 8601.